# Python - sklearn pipeline SVC f_regression - get column names

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I'm trying to the column names from this code snippet:

```
anova_filter = SelectKBest(f_regression, k=10)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
anova_svm = make_pipeline(anova_filter, clf)
f_reg_features = anova_svm.fit(df_train, df_train_y)
```

I tried some other suggestions such as this one but I wasn't able to get it to work:

[How to get feature names selected by feature elimination in sklearn pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633460/how-to-get-feature-names-selected-by-feature-elimination-in-sklearn-pipeline)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you want to get the features selected from the SelectKBest which are passed onto the svm?

Comment: Correct, but I have been unable to get other methods to work.

Comment: What about `df_train.columns[anova_svm.steps[0][1].get_support()]`

Comment: That works thank you.  Where did find the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [eli5](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5) library (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors) you can do it like this:

```
# the original example:
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_regression
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
import pandas as pd

X, y = make_classification(n_features=5, n_informative=5, n_redundant=0)
df_train = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
df_train_y = pd.DataFrame(y)

anova_filter = SelectKBest(f_regression, k=3)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
anova_svm = make_pipeline(anova_filter, clf)
f_reg_features = anova_svm.fit(df_train, df_train_y)
```

and then:

```
import eli5
feat_names = eli5.transform_feature_names(anova_filter, list(df.columns))
```

It works in a way similar to Vivek Kumar's suggestion; the advantage is unified API - there is no need to remember such snippets for each transformer.

If you replace SVC(kernel='linear') with sklearn.linear_model.LinearSVM (which should be also much faster), you can do this:

```
eli5.show_weights(anova_svm, feature_names=list(df.columns))
```

and get a table like this:

[image]

Comment: That works thank you, just like with the answer where did you find it?

Comment: I'm one of the authors of eli5 library; SelectKBest support was contributed to this library by Joel Nothman (one of scikit-learn developers). So I'm aware that eli5 library exisits, and I had to look at implementation before merging the pull request. Either way, `SelectKBest.get_support` method is documented in scikit-learn docs - see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.get_support.

Comment: Cool Library, I'll make sure to tell my other Python friends about it.  Thanks again.